# Looking for a term or phrase to describe a discussion where there is no one right answer

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

I am looking for a term or phrase to describe a discussion where there is no one right answer (e.g., tabs versus spaces). Both sides could be equally right, and the arguments are made mostly from their own perspective, rather than being factual.

Comment: I don't think a discussion necessarily has answers, let alone a single, right one. We say an *open-ended* discussion, but that refers more to its scope/focus.

Comment: They might be referred to as [religious issues](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/R/religious-issues.html), sometimes ironically. But the question is too vague to answer: such open-ended discussions can be vicious and passionate with no agreement (e.g. over abortion), or trivial and friendly where you agree to differ (e.g. which flavor of ice cream is best). You need to think what kind of discussion you want to describe.

Answer (score 2):

### moot point

A **moot point** is a topic which has been talked to the point of exhaustion without any decision being made.

- The use of tabs versus spaces has become something of a moot point
- Whether Shakespeare even wrote these two sonnets is a moot point, but the fact remains that they are among the most well-known verses in English.

“Moot point” is the most common noun-phrase using the adjective “*moot*”:

- **[moot](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/moot)** (*adj.*) often discussed or argued about but having no definite answer.

Unless you are using “moot point”, you generally describe something as *being* moot rather than applying the adjective to the noun:

- **No**: It is a mostly moot argument
- **Yes**: The argument is mostly moot.

###### to moot

The verb form of “moot” is also used in British English to describe something that is put forward for discussion, usually in a political context:

- “**Hard border mooted by UK in 1980s** : Officials from the British government were proposing a physical ‘hard’ border at the height of the Troubles in Northern Ireland, it was revealed in declassified state papers released last week under the 30 year rule.” - *Irish Independent*, 6. January, 2018.

This goes back to the original meaning of a “moot”, an Anglo-Saxon term for an assembly held to discuss how a clan or tribe would be ruled.

#### *never* say “mute”!

There’s a common error in American English of describing arguments as “mute points”. Please don’t do it.

Answer (score 0):

"Six of one, half a dozen of the other" if both sides are similar or identical.

"Tempest in a teapot" if the issue is trivial and not worth arguing about.